# Database not found error when connecting to Derby network server

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx, derby, javadb

I'm having problems initializing my javadb network server and setting a connection to it. It's a JavaFX program.

This is what I have so far:

```
try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        javadbserver = new NetworkServerControl();
        javadbserver.start(null);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGuiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Where is your JavaDB embedded Driver?");
        return;
    }

    String dbName = "mydb";
    String dbUser = "auser";
    String dbPass = "password";

    PreparedStatement prepstmt;

    try {
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mydb;user=auser;password=password");
        System.out.println("Went through!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainGuiController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I always catch the second exception.

If I right click on the javadb service in netbeans and choose connect, everything runs smoothly. [Actually it'd be nice to know what code or program java runs in the background when I select that]

In my projects list under libraries I see derby.jar, derbyclient.jar and derbynet.jar

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Here's the error I get

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: The connection was refused because the database mydb was not found.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
    at mydb.MainGuiController.initialize(MainGuiController.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
    at mydb.mydb.start(mydb.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: The connection was refused because the database mydb was not found.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseRDBNFNRM(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseAccessRdbError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseACCRDBreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readAccessDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowUSRIDPWDconnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You're just swallowing the exception! At least print a stacktrace if you're not going to handle or "duck" it. Once you get the stacktrace and still not sure what's going on, include it in your question.

Comment: yep. how silly of me.Question edited

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the JDBC url, it's looks like you're trying to connect to a Derby server vs. an embedded instance. If you are trying to connect to a server instance, here are some considerations:

- did you start the server yourself, did mydb already exists?
- if not, did you pass in the correct params to create (e.g. ;create=true)
  `example: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/dbname;create=true`
- if mydb did exists, are you pointing the server to the correct location?

  - also, depending on what was used to start derby (e.g. embedded vs network driver) default database locations are different as well. You can read [about it here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html#ij_ns_client)

Basically the exception you're getting is that Derby's saying it can't find your database - it's basically a path issue.

Comment: Yes. Stupid stupid me! I forgot to include the full path because I forgot that the default in windows is under C:/users/myUserName/.netbeans-derby/mydb

Answer (score 2):

If you're using netbeans, you should fix this by going into the connection properties and adding a property. Under "property" type "create" and under "value" type "true".