# Netbeans 7.3.1 Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

Recently I'm working on this little project with Java EE and I need to use derby database , but every time I go to service->Database and try to connect to my jdbc:derby I get this error :

Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//sample using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (java.netConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.).

and this exception :

```
Wed Oct 29 15:05:26 EET 2014 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1131)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControWed Oct 29 15:05:26 EET 2014 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessContrller.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.maiolContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1131)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
n(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try the hint from here http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaDB_grant_permissions

JDK 7u51 comes with some security improvements which are causing problems with starting Java DB on this Java version.

When you try to start DB from NetBeans you will probably get the Exception:

```
 java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
```

The same exception you will get while starting using script /db/bin/startNetworkServer

Because there is no suitable way to fix it on the NetBeans side and this should be fixed on the side of the Java DB.

There are several ways how to deal with this problem. I will mention only the easiest way. You have to start DB manually from command line.

Start Java DB with -noSecurityManager argument.

```
  <JDK 7u51 location>/db/bin/startNetworkServer -noSecurityManager
```

Comment: OK after i started derby network server i get this : (The connection was refused because the database sample was not found)

Comment: This might help you solve that part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375504/database-not-found-error-when-connecting-to-derby-network-server

Comment: Okey... i dont really get it how to solve it :/ (new to this stuff)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add start page in project property.
Open Project property. Then choose tab run. Then add your project start page to relative URL text box. Mine is "/index.jsp".

Sorry if i have some mistake in english grammar.